# Make select dropdown required using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have a form that has all optional parts. But, if you type anything into any of the inputs, JQuery makes all the inputs required (so you can either fill out the whole thing or nothing at all if you don't have anything to add).

This works great and looks like this:

```
$('#submitForm').click(function () {
    givenNameVal = $('#givenName').val();
    familyNameVal = $('#familyName').val();
    emailVal = $('#email').val();
    phoneVal = $('#phoneNumber').val();
    if (givenNameVal == "" && familyNameVal == "" && emailVal == "" && phoneVal == "") {
        $('#familyName').prop("required", false);
        $('#email').prop("required", false);
        $('#phoneNumber').prop("required", false);
        $('#givenName').prop("required", false);
    } else {
        $('#familyName').prop("required", true);
        $('#email').prop("required", true);
        $('#phoneNumber').prop("required", true);
        $('#givenName').prop("required", true);
    }
});
```

(I know I can make the code look cleaner and will do so once I have a full solution)

The issue I'm having is that I also have a select drop down that will not let me make it required. I have tried both

```
    $('#relationshipDropDown').prop("required", true);
    $('#relationshipDropDown').attr("required", true);
```

And neither work. I have tried making it required from the start, and then trying to take away the required tag after the fact, and it doesn't work.

Thoughts?

**Unnecessary backstory for those who want more information:**
The form is for people to add other entities to their 'insurance' plan. It is absolutely not required for them to add anything, but if they want to add something, we need all the information. There's actually a lot more to the code (address, etc) that I didn't add. The relationship drop down is 'relationship to owner of the plan' and is required.

Additionally, the drop down has several hidden inputs that become required if that selection is selected (i.e. if 'other' is selected, then a hidden input shows up, or if 'training agency' is selected then a list of partner agencies shows up). This is why it has to be a drop down or whatnot and not just a regular input box.

Thank you!

Edit: Before I start modifying my code, here is the code for the dropdown

```
<div class="input-group  mb-3 col-md-4 col-sm-12">
<select class="form-control" name="relationshipDropDown" id="relationshipDropDown">
    <option value="0" hidden>Relationship to Entity</option>
    <option value="1">Dive Boat</option>
    <option value="2"> Training Agency</option>
    <option value="3">Educational Institutions</option>
    <option value="4">Government Entity</option>
    <option value="5">Hotel</option>
    <option value="6">Marina</option>
    <option value="7">Motel</option>
    <option value="8">Pool/Facility Owner</option>
    <option value="9">Resort</option>
    <option value="10">Resort Dive Operator</option>
    <option value="11">Retailer</option>
    <option value="13">Other</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Post your html code, if possible in snippet

Comment: Are you sure that there is no default option in the drop down that is getting the "selected" attribute by default, thus satisfying "required"? Just making sure.

Comment: hey check out my code  down here. it would help u to access required attribute as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without your HTML I don't know if you've already done something like this, but here is what has worked for me in the past.

Make the first option in the select something like:

```
<option value="">Choose One:</option>
```

Then, in your `$('#submitForm').click(function ()`, you can check if that is still the selected value of the control:

```
let rdd = $('#relationshipDropDown').val();
if (rdd == ""){
    //Send user back to Go
}
```

Comment: This was perfect. All I did was change the value="0" to value="". I was able to retain the hidden. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure that you have default value as null in select.please refer
>   the code below it would help you.

```html
<form>
<label>Please select a number to submit the form:</label>
<select id="select" required>
<option></option>
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
<option>3</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

Comment: wouldn't this make it always required? I only want it required if one of the other fields is filled out.

Comment: @HumanHickory it will work even if all other fields are filled out.

Comment: Right, but I don't want it to be required by default. Your solution as far as adding the default value of null was correct. I do appreciate that. But I didn't add the required tag to the HTML; I add the required tag through JQuery if something else is filled out. But, regardless, your recommendation worked. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to include a default blank option in your dropdown input. Without the blank option, the first option is selected therefore the required validation passes.

```
<select id="relationshipDropDown">
    <option selected value=''>-- Select an option --</option>
    <option value="father">Father</option>
    <option value="mother">Mother</option>
    <option value="sibling">Sibling</option>
</select>
```

The code below makes the dropdown list required as expected

```
$('#relationshipDropDown').prop("required", true);
```

Here is [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ezulfiqar/jw27tqLh/6/) example with working validation or you run the code snippet below.

```js
$('#submitForm').click(function () {
    givenNameVal = $('#givenName').val();
    familyNameVal = $('#familyName').val();
    emailVal = $('#email').val();
    phoneVal = $('#phoneNumber').val();
    if (givenNameVal == "" && familyNameVal == "" && emailVal == "" && phoneVal == "") {
        $('#familyName').prop("required", false);
        $('#email').prop("required", false);
        $('#phoneNumber').prop("required", false);
        $('#givenName').prop("required", false);
        $('#relationshipDropDown').prop("required", false);
    } else {
        $('#familyName').prop("required", true);
        $('#email').prop("required", true);
        $('#phoneNumber').prop("required", true);
        $('#givenName').prop("required", true);
        $('#relationshipDropDown').prop("required", true);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/action_page.php">
  Given name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="givenName" name="givenName" value="">
  <br>
  Family name:<br>
  <input type="text" id="familyName" name="familyName" value="">
  <br>
  Email:<br>
  <input type="text" id="email" name="email" value="">
  <br>
  Phone:<br>
  <input type="text" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" value="">
  <br>
  <select id="relationshipDropDown">
    <option selected value=''>-- Select an option --</option>
    <option value="father">Father</option>
    <option value="mother">Mother</option>
    <option value="sibling">Sibling</option>
</select>
  <br><br>
  <input id="submitForm" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Visual Studio was upset that "selected value" wasn't "selected value ="" " BUT your solution overall was correct. I really appreciate your help! Thank you!

Comment: Ah I see. I didn't know you were using Visual Studio. But i do want to mention that `selected` and `value` are two different properties. `selected` selects this value by default whereas `value=''` allows you to add an blank option for validation. I have updated the solution to include `value=''`